# How can i get selected value from a select component

Tags: angular, typescript, components

How can I get the selected value from a select component?

select.component.ts:

```
export class PfSelectComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  @Input() options : Array<Object>;

}
```

select.component.html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option.value">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>

select value: {{selectedValue}}
```

{{selectValue}} does not show the value selected in the component.

Comment: Did you add `selectedValue` as a member of `PfSelectComponent` class?

Comment: `@Input() selectedValue;` Like this? did not work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

select.component.html

You shoud use [value] not [ngValue] : 
[ngValue] => [value]

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" class="form-control" >
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>

select value: {{selectedValue}}
```

select.component.ts

and add public selectedValue;

```
export class PfSelectComponent implements OnInit {

  public selectedValue;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  @Input() options : Array<Object>;
}
```

I tested this with

```
options = [
    {
      value: 1,
      name : "1"
    },
    {
      value: 2,
      name : "2"
    },
    {
      value: 3,
      name : "3"
    }
  ]
```

It works well :)